# Wrapping localStorage in Ember-cli Demo

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

In the example code below

http://jsbin.com/ketaqiwe/embed?js,output

I am able to select a color, and the computed property will change based on the color but the localstorage will also change.
But if I open the console and edit the localstorage and change the color manually a storage event will trigger and the action will change the color anyway.
The challenge I am having is triggering the `eventListener` within Ember-cli.
I'm not sure whats the best practice is for this example to be done inside of ember-cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an addon to handle it for you? https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/README.md